# Android Save Files to EPUB

Tags: android, file, format, epub

i want to make a programme thats edit to epub file format .

So i unzipped to epub and editing on the html file . But after editing unzipped files not anymore epub format. How can i compile them to epub format again . Are there any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that by "But after editing unzipped files not anymore epub format" you mean that you zipped again the book directory, but when you run epubcheck on the resulting .epub file, it generates validation errors.

Usually, this is due to two errors:

1. you need to zip so that the "mimefile" and the "META-INF" are in the root of the resulting archive;
2. per EPUB specification (see http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-ocf.html#sec-zip-container-mime ), the "mimefile" must be the first entry of the resulting ZIP container, and it must be stored (uncompressed). All the other files might be either stored (uncompressed) or compressed as you wish, the latter choice being obviously more common.

Check the documentation of the ZIP library of your programming language for learning how to create an empty ZIP file and to add an entry uncompressed or compressed.

Comment: Thank you so much.I can do it on windows manuelly  .  Do you now any package or method that can direct and edit to zip file in Android Studio ?

Comment: There are several commercial EPUB SDKs. If you want a free library, check http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib out. Otherwise, simply use the Android API, setting either STORED (not compressed, for mimetype) or DEFLATED (compressed, all other files): http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#setMethod(int)